# nginx strip URI parameter

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

1. there is a nginx with `php-fpm` installed. there is a subdirectory `/shop` with `main.php` inside.
2. `main.php` works in a following way: if request is `example.com/shop/product/123` - it's requesting `example.com/shop/main.php?route=/product/123/` (this works with nginx+apache)

here is the `.htaccess` content

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|jpg|png|img)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) main.php?route=$1
```

What I've tried to do:

```
location ^~ /shop/product {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/main.php?route=$1 ;
}
```

-- this is not working, it is returning a 404

```
location /shop {
try_files $uri $uri/ /shop/main.php?route=$uri;
}
```

this returns incorrect page because `$uri` is `/shop/product/123`

What I'm trying to achieve is to strip 'shop' word from `$uri`.

Answer (score 1):

Using second `try_files` doesn't make sense at all, it is just an extra overhead (two kernel `stat` calls). Moreover, the `$1` variable takes some value after doing some matching against a regex pattern containing a numbered capture group, which isn't a job for the `try_files` directive. Use `rewrite` directive instead:

```
location /shop/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/shop(/.*) /shop/main.php?route=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) that splved your problem by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.